# testing if something inside the function has an unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, tdd

I'm using mocha and chai for testing.

I have a function, that takes another function and sort of wraps around it, and calls it while doing a few other things when the `.call()` method is invoked.

like so:

```
let tracker = trackerFactory({
  watchFunction: somefunction
})

tracker.call() //does some things, calls somefunction, does more things...
```

Now I'm trying to test it for handling a function that when calls returns a promise that rejects.

```
it("handles a rejection by the watched function", (done) => {
  let tracker = trackerFactory({
    watchFunction: () => {
      Promise.reject(new Error("random error"))
    }
  })

  expect(function() {
    tracker.call();
  }).to.not.throw("random error");

  done();
})
```

eventually, this test should pass, but I'm doing TDD so I've not yet implemented the mechanism that handles a rejection. The issue is, that this test passes regardless, even though node displays a warning:

```
    ✓ handles a rejection by the watched function
(node:4347) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: random error
(node:4347) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

So my question is, how do I test for cases that displays this warning? Or, in other words, how do I test whether something inside the function, has an unhandled rejection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I eventually did, and I feel pretty comfortable with this solution:

I used chai-as-promised and edited my test code to be as such:

```
it("handles a rejection by the watched function", () => {
  let tracker = trackerFactory({
    watchFunction: () => {
      return Promise.reject(new Error("random error"))
    }
  })

  return tracker.call().should.be.fulfilled;
})
```

This will fail if `tracker.call()` does not return a Promise, or if it returns a promise that does not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Even with TDD, since you know that the test is for promise rejection, you could implement a promise rejection from the watchFunction, like so:

```
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (true)
            resolve();
        else
          // throw new Error("Promise rejected")
            reject();
    });
```

It is just a template of a promise not yet implemented much like `throw new MethodNotImplemented` exception.

And in the test, handle the promise rejection, like so,

```
it("handles Promise rejection",async ()=>{
    await watchFunction().then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Promise rejected")
   // assert.equal(error.message,"Promise rejected")
})
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm not calling `watchFunction`, I'm setting it. Calling `watchFunction` by using the module will actually be done by calling `tracker.call()`. `tracker.call()` will do some things, among which it will call `watchFunction`, which could fail/reject. I can't call `watchFunction` directly from the test, this willl defeat the purpose